# Fix header to top of browser issue when user resizes the browser

Tags: jquery

I've got an issue with my fixed scrollable header, basically the way it works is the header is scrollable, once the header reaches the top of the browser it then becomes fixed, so far this works perfectly fine.

The issue is, when the user resizes the browser height, in order for it to work correctly the user needs to refresh the page, anyone know how I can edit the script in order to work after the user resizes, I tried using .resize but my code doesn't work correctly.

here's a fiddle of the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/c9cbvj58/2/

Here's my edited code using .resize: that doesn't work but i've added this to show what i've done.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var elementPosition = $('header').offset();

var fixFunction = $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
        $('header').addClass("stick");
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass("stick");
    }    
});

$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    fixFunction();
}).trigger('resize');

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c9cbvj58/5/)

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    elementPosition = $('header').offset();
});
```

When change the height must update the offset