# Stop div from scrolling after div with dynamic height

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I'm trying to make a website using Joomla and would like to stop the menu from scrolling after it reaches the top of the site. It was working for me using the following code

```
$("document").ready(function($){
    var nav = $('#rt-header');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
            nav.addClass("f-nav");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("f-nav");
        }
    });
});
```

at least as long as the div before rt-header has a fixed heigth. But as soon as I ad a responsive element (which results in an dynamic height if I get it right) the code is not sufficient and the header jumps as soon as I start scrolling.

This is my first contact with jquery, so sorry if I miss something obvious. I'm working in a local test environment, so I cant point you to the actual site.

Answer (score 0):

A post like this is [Fix header to top of browser issue when user resizes the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464729/fix-header-to-top-of-browser-issue-when-user-resizes-the-browser/26464940#26464940)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c9cbvj58/5/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var elementPosition = $('header').offset();

var fixFunction = $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
        $('header').addClass("stick");
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass("stick");
    }    
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    elementPosition = $('header').offset();
});

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. The code you entered seems to work just fine after a resice of the site, but if the site is just loaded without said resice, the header jumps to the top as soon as I start scrolling.